# react-native: pass Menu value to the function as a parameter

Tags: react-native

I am using menu in my react-native app as follows

```
 <Menu onSelect={(value) => alert(`User selected the number ${value}`)}>
  <MenuTrigger>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>&#8942;</Text>
  </MenuTrigger>
  <MenuOptions>
    <MenuOption value={1}>
      <Text>One</Text>
    </MenuOption>
    <MenuOption value={2}>
      <Text>Two</Text>
    </MenuOption>
  </MenuOptions>
</Menu>
```

I want to pass ${value} to the function as a parameter. I am trying to do this as follows

```
 <Menu opened={this.state.opened}  renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu} onBackdropPress={() => 
 this.onBackdropPress()} onSelect={(value) => this.navigateMenu(${value})}>
```

as well as

```
  <Menu opened={this.state.opened}  renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu} onBackdropPress={() => 
  this.onBackdropPress()} onSelect={() => this.navigateMenu(${value})}>
```

but above code giving me an error can anyone help me to solve this, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using the wrong syntax.

`${variable}` without nothing will fire an error. That syntax into alert is good, because there you are using **template literals** (read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals )

Here you just need to place the variable like this:

`onSelect={() => this.navigateMenu(value)}`